# How do I connect a nozzle to a hose that doesn't have a threaded connector?

Tags: hoses

My garden hose does not have a threaded female connector at the end. In that case, how can I connect a nozzle to the hose? I tried to find if there is any type of threaded connector that can be inserted into the hose to make a connection but couldn't find any. Is there any such kind of connector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, search for a male garden hose replacement fitting, they are available at most home stores for under $5.  They have a barbed fitting that goes into the hose end and a clamp. (On garden hoses and pipes the male end has the threads on the outside and is furthest from the water source, since it goes "inside" of the female end)

http://www.lowes.com/cd_Repair+a+Garden+Hose_1400094211947_

Comment: And make sure to get one that will work with the size of the hose. Too big a fitting on a small diameter hose, fitting won't fit in. Too small a fitting and it could leak.

Comment: If possible you can cut an inch or two off the hose and take it along to the store to ensure the new fitting is the correct size.

Comment: Many hardware stores have a jig to attach hose end fittings, and a variety of fittings for different diameter hoses. I paid $8 to have a crushed fitting on the end of a 100 foot hose replaced.